# Combine data into smaller discrete intervals

Tags: f#, mapping, intervals, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have a pair of input arrays, or a list of (key, value) tuples if you prefer. What's an elegant and performant way to combine values that have indices falling in a certain interval? For example, if the interval (or 'bin') size is 10 then the values of all indices from `0 < x <= 10` would be combined, as would the values of indices from `10 < x <= 20` and so on.  I want:

```
let interval = 10
let index  = [| 6; 12; 18; 24 |]
let value  = [| a;  b;  c;  d |]
result = [| a; b + c; d |]
```

The crudest way to do this would be to use a whole lot of if, else if statements (the index range has a defined upper limit). I got close with

```
for i = 0 to index.Length do
    result.[Math.Floor(index.[i]/10] += value.[Math.Floor(index.[i]/10]
```

but this is doing `0 <= x < 10`, not `0 < x <= 10`.

I also tried assuming the indices are ordered and evenly spaced, with

```
for i = 1 : ( index.Length - 1 ) / valuesPerBin
    valueRange = ((i-1)*valuesPerBin + 1) : i*valuesPerBin )
    result(i) = sum(value(valueRange))
```

which is nice but obviously breaks if there is a non integer number of values per bin.

What's the best way of doing this in F#? Is there a name or an existing function for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Excuse the sudden switch from F# array.[index] notation to MATLAB array(index) notation.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let interval = 10 
let index = [6;12;18;24] 
let value =[101;102;103;104] 
let intervals = List.map (fun e -> e/interval) index
let keys = List.map2(fun e1 e2 -> (e1,e2)) intervals value
let skeys = Seq.ofList keys
let result = skeys
             |>Seq.groupBy (fun p -> fst p) 
             |>Seq.map (fun p -> snd p)
             |>Seq.map(fun s -> Seq.sumBy (fun p -> snd p) s)
```

***result*** will be [**101;205;104**] (as a Seq).

If you want to convert to an array, apply Seq.toArray.

Is it what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the surrounding code to use 
`0 <= x < 10` instead of `0 < x <= 10`. In my case this was just a simple definition change in another function, allowing me to use 
`for i = 0 to index.Length do
    result.[Math.Floor(index.[i]/10] += value.[Math.Floor(index.[i]/10]`, which is much simpler and terser syntax than the alternatives.

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.